# Building a small timer app, why won't app timer stop both labels?

Tags: swift, button, timer

I'm in the process of building a timer app

I have a button that starts the timer and changes both labels
I have another button that stops the timer with .invalidete.

the problem is when the timer starts both labels change at the set rate they are suppose to

But when I hit the stop button only the 2nd timer label stops changing, the 1st label seems to keep going I don't know why

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer = NSTimer()
    var counter = 0
    var counter2 = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!

    @IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject){
        counter = 0
        label.text = String(counter)

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: "updateCounter", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "updateCounter2", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }


    func updateCounter2(){
        counter2 += 1
        label2.text = String(counter2)
    }


    func updateCounter(){
        counter += 1
        label.text = String(counter)
    }

    @IBAction func stop(sender: AnyObject) {
        timer.invalidate()
        timer.invalidate()
    }


}
```

Comment: You're assigning both timers to the same variable `timer`, change one of those to something else and it'll work

Answer (score 0):

What you wan't to do is something like this:

```
var timer:NSTimer!
var timer2:NSTimer!
var counter = 0
var counter2 = 0

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!

@IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject){
    counter = 0
    label.text = String(counter)

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: "updateCounter", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


    timer2 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "updateCounter2", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}


func updateCounter2(){
    counter2 += 1
    label2.text = String(counter2)
}


func updateCounter(){
    counter += 1
    label.text = String(counter)
}

@IBAction func stop(sender: AnyObject) {
    timer.invalidate()
    timer2.invalidate()
}
```

Watch [this talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/414/) in value types from WWDC 2015, it explains a couple of things about OOP that you might find useful.